# How to import from command line and then iterate over imported modules?

Tags: python, import

I have a folder structure like this:

```
package_name/
|-- module1
|-- module2
|-- module3
```

What I need to do is `import package_name`, and then iterate over each of the modules, running code upon them one after another. The import is given at the command line, so I can't control that ahead of time. So a user might say, `run_script.py --modules='package_name.module1'` or the user might simply say, `run_script.py --modules='package_name`.

I can do `from package_name import *`, and that will import everything defined in my `__all__` variable in `__init__.py`, but from there I'm a bit stumped.

For my next step, I need a way of doing:

```
for module in imported:
    module.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a function like this to import a module by path:

```
def import_by_path(path):
  if '.' not in path:
    return __import__(path, globals(), locals())

  path, module = path.rsplit('.', 1)
  mod = __import__(path, globals(), locals(), [module])

  try:
    return getattr(mod, module)
  except AttributeError:
    raise ImportError, "Could not import %s" % path
```

Use like this:

```
mod = import_by_name("itertools")
```

Or in your case:

```
for mod in map(import_by_name, imported):
  mod.run()
```

Comment: I didn't end up using this as is, but it gave me all the direction I needed to sort out my own technique. Thank you!